# Floor Function for integers: find the lowest value to the tens place

Tags: r

Someone must have done this, but I am not seeing an answer.  I want to round a vector of numbers to the closest tenth place.  I know that I can use the floor function if its a decimal, but that doesn't work for whole numbers

```
# this works, for decimals
floor( 9576.44 )
# I would like this to return 9570
round( 9576 , -1 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a function divides your number by 10 and gives you the whole number portion of the quotient.  Then multiples the number by 10 to give you the number you imputed with a floor at the tens place

```
newfloor <- function(X){ 
    (X %/% 10 ) *10}

newfloor(9576)
```

Answer (score 2):

So you just always want to clip off the last few digits to round down? How about this function

```
clip <- function(x, d=1) x - x %% 10**d
```

It just does some modulus math to find the last digit of the number and subtract it off.

Then you can do

```
clip( 9576 , 1 )
# [1] 9570
clip( 9576 , 2 )
# [1] 9500
```

Or still using floor, you could just divide and multiple by 10

```
floor(9576 /10) *10
# [1] 9570
```